# Unable to use ActiveAdmin helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to use custom methods in `ActiveAdmin`. I added helper file in `app/helpers/active_admin/views_helper.rb`:

```
module ActiveAdmin::ViewsHelper
  def currency_row(name)
    row name do
      number_to_currency(deal.send(name), precision: 0)
    end
  end
end
```

But I have next error:

```
undefined method `row' for #<#<Class:0x007fe83f0c0650>:0x007fe83f0b92b0>
```

Obviously, I should include some modules to use ActiveAdmin methods, but I can't find what exactly.

PS: I want to use `currency_row :amount` instead of:

```
row :amount do |deal|
  number_to_currency(deal.amount, precision: 0)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not work because `row` method is not a helper and it comes from ActiveAdmin DSL.

While I would recommend against it, what you are trying to accomplish can be achieved by monkey patching the class `ActiveAdmin::Views::AttributesTable` which [defines](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/2f7703600953b05e629e101a2b4d5a4c8844740c/lib/active_admin/views/components/attributes_table.rb#L22-L43) the row method.

You can alternatively create a helper and pass it self, using which row method can be accessed. However it will fail if used outside AttributesTable context.

I would recommend just using the last snippet of code you have written, which is IMHO sufficiently concise:

```
row :loan_amount do |deal|
  number_to_currency(deal.amount, precision: 0)
end
```